# RouterLink with named outlet and base path

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, routerlink

I have an issue with the routing of my app:

I have a base  and 2  and

My route is currently

```
<router-outlet> path : ''
       <router-outlet name=1> : ''
             <router-outlet name=2> : ''
```

and I want to go to

```
 <router-outlet> path : ''
        <router-outlet name=1> : ''
              <router-outlet name=2> : 'search'
```

I tried this but I can't figured out:

```
<a [routerLink]="['',{ outlets: {'named1': [''],'named2': ['search']}} ]"> GO TO SEARCH </a>
```

I can't even find the right url because of the  having an empty(base: '/') route

I keep getting this error:

*NavigationError {id: 2, url: "/(seetickets://content:search)", error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''*

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: I tried making this plunker but unable to make it work
https://plnkr.co/edit/gV6kMSRlogjBKnh3JHU3

Comment: sorry, buddy, can't help without a plunker, try maybe https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4hesp